# Le mot "parlance"

Tags: traduction, anglais, étymologie, histoire, évolution

I was reading a mathematical textbook and I encountered the following passage:

> Ordinary words which in common **parlance** have many different shades of meaning are used in mathematics with very specific meanings.

As another example from another book:

> Furthermore, we restrict our development of the mathematical parlance to only that which is required to rigorously present the physical concepts.

I was sure that the world *parlance* comes from parler+-ance and this is indeed the case as one can verify. Suffix -ance is a common one in French language (ambiance, ambulance, impédance, etc.). I am wondering why parlance does not exist in the French language. (it is translated by jargon, langage, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Parlance* existe en français.

- [Il a été usuel aux siècles XIV / XV](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/parlance)
- [Il est toujours utilisé en sémiotique.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Yu5YAAAAMAAJ&q=parlance%20histoire&dq=parlance%20histoire&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAipHn0pPkAhUvzYUKHWBGA1UQ6AEIQzAF)

Dans le registre commun, je crois qu'il a subi la concurrence de *jactance*.

Pour répondre à un commentaire de l'OP :
*parlance* ne vient pas immédiatement comme écrit dans l'OP de *parler* + suffixe ance.
*parler* donne d'abord son participe présent *parlant*, ce dernier est par suite substantivé de façon classique -> *parlance*.
De façon totalement indépendante du suffixe et du verbe (usuels ou non) le dérivé d'un verbe, ici un substantif, a une vie autonome. Il peut un temps correspondre à un besoin puis... soumis aux lois de l'usage, disparaitre.

Comment: Alors il est vieilli comme partance, non ?

Comment: @Dimitris : Hors lexique spécialisé, on peut même le considérer ***très** vieilli* voire carrément *démotivé*. Ce qui n'est pas le cas de *partance*. On connaît toujours les *trains en partance pour...*

Comment: Merci ! Mais pourquoi un tel mot qui est fondé sur un suffixe commun du français est considéré (très) vieilli ?

Comment: C'est le dictionnaire Livio (android apk) qui l'a indiqué cela. parler+-ance). Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @Dimitris : Eu égard à la langue de tes ancêtres, je t'offrirais volontiers une comparaison : Tu sais que la substantivisation du participe présent est chose très commune en Grec ancien. (Ce qui nous a d'ailleurs posé de nombreux pb de traduction tant le français offre moins de libertés) Tu sais certainement le nombre de verbes grecs restés usuels alors que le substantif correspondant a été oublié.

Comment: @Dimitris Le suffixe -ance pour former des substantifs sur la base de participes n'est plus productif, -age and la dérivation directe avec suffixe nul (gêner -> la gêne) l'ayant largement remplacé. Une fois qu'un mot est forme figée, plutôt que le produit d'une dérivation usuelle, il est susceptible d'être remplacé naturellement par un processus naturel de remplacement lexical

Comment: Tu pourrais aussi évoquer *parlure*.

Answer (score -2):

En anglais « parlance »  signifie « façon particulière d'utiliser les mots ou de s'exprimer » et le on trouve  en connexion avec  des expressions telles que « common parlance » et « modern parlance » ou avec les professions (legal parlance ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=legal+parlance&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clegal%20parlance%3B%2Cc0)).

Le [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/parlance) donne pour son sens 2 possibilités: 1/ jargon 2/ idiome.

Je pense donc que l'expression « common parlance » peut se traduire ici par « idiome courant » ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=idiome+courant&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cidiome%20courant%3B%2Cc0)).

[common parlance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20common%20parlance): formal,  used by many people in ordinary conversation

Comment: As usual +1 because I appreciate your effort to answer my question. But if one wants to be purist and speaking very strictly you have provide no precise answer to my question (why parlance does not exist in the French language?). Thanks nevertheless. I guess in the context of the mathematical text is more appropriately translated by jargon.

Comment: @Dimitris I think you err; the expression is not applied to the language of mathemetics in this sentence; it is not jargon, it is rather ordinary speech.

Comment: @Dimitris That's right, I didn't answer that question and I didn't have the slightest idea of an answer, but neither does [this answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/38086/17649) give a clue to the reason; it's only in reading this [comment](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/7738/eau-qui-dort) that we can begin to consider a plausible cause and it is only in the realm of possibilities; that comment is the best answer as to the why of the disppearance of "parlance" in the French dictionary.